# Regex split on comma don't split on comma between double quotes

Tags: javascript

I have been searching every where but can't seem to find a solution that fully matches my requirement.

I need to split the following string on a comma but need to exclude the comma between double quotes.

Here is the string that needs splitting.

```
var s = "36291,362,91,AN - UTS - 36291,0.0050,0.0050,,TRUE,,\"001721,00599\",2017-03-06 00:00,Netherlands Antilles,AN,0,999999999,,,,,,,,";
```

The required end result needs to be

```
var a = ['36291','362,91','AN - UTS - 36291','0.0050','0.0050','','TRUE','','\"001721,00599\"','2017-03-06 00:00','Netherlands Antilles','AN','0','999999999','','','','','','','',];
```

I have been battling for more than a day yet haven't found any joy.
There need to be a simple solution that I'm overlooking.

Closest I have come is

```
var r = s.split(/(".*?"|[^",\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/);
```

This works in the regex tester [regextester](https://regex101.com)

but not when running it in my browser. None of the suggested results matches my question.

Comment: The required end result is not valid thus making things not clear. Please post a valid one.

Comment: "*There need to be a simple solution*" - no. You're trying to parse CSV. `split` isn't going to cut it.